# Geometry nodes not rendering

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3C34FkF9nw

Everything shows clearly through the viewport, but when I try to render, only the original mesh (a plane) shows. I'm not sure whether I have messed up somewhere in the nodes or there is something wrong with my setup.

Here are my geonodes, as well as the resulting render:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also noticed my render doesn't show up in Cycles render preview, while it does on Eevee.

[image]

[image]

Comment: as often, share your file: that will help people to find a solution for you. Please use https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know how to do that. I have uploaded my archive the way you said I should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 'group output' here:

[image]

Remove it and as CDRX said replace the viewer by a group output.

Comment: OH MY GOD, THANK YOU SO MUCH! YOU'VE LITERALLY SAVED ME! Thank you so very much. :')

Answer (score 1):

Your very last node is a *Viewer*, a node that lets you temporary preview the output of your node tree at different points. It's a debugging tool, not an output.

Replace it with a *Group Output* and it'll work.

Comment: Hi, CDRX! I already tried that, but it's still not working. :(